# Can a Content Security Policy (CSP) enable *new* unsafe behavior?

Tags: content-security-policy

Does the design and implementation of the content security policy standard allow for the introduction of *new* unsafe behavior that wasn't there prior to having any CSP at all?

For example if my starting point is having no CSP headers or policy at all and I then introduce a CSP which contains:

- unsafe-eval
- unsafe-inline

Is it now *less* secure (e.g. has it enabled something that was not allowed prior to having any CSP)?

Comment: It can certainly introduce bugs of page functionality that is being blocked by the CSP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal of Content-Security-Policy is to add an **additional security layer** and not relax existing security settings. From [Content Security Policy Level 3 - Introduction](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#intro):

> ... use to lock down their applications in various ways, **mitigating the risk** of content injection vulnerabilities such as cross-site scripting, and **reducing the privilege** with which their applications execute.

So CSP cannot be used to relax the Same Origin Policy. That would be [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) instead.

As for your example of `unsafe-inline` and `unsafe-eval`: With no CSP these are enabled by default. So a CSP which has these directives does not relax the existing default security settings.

Answer (score 1):

No CSP means no restrictions. Any CSP is better than no CSP.

---

I like to read a CSP directive `img-src ___` or `frame-src ___` out loud as "images/frames are not allowed except from ___".

So this CSP:

```
Content-Security-Policy: img-src https://example.com
```

would be read out loud as "images are not allowed except for from https://example.com". What about frames? They are not specified, therefore they are allowed. Typically a page will set a CSP will set a very restrictive `default-src` and then specifically override that to allow the external resources that it needs.

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; img-src https://example.com
```

which I read out loud as "Things are only allowed from self, except for images which are not allowed except for from https://example.com"

If a CSP directive (ex.: `frame-src`) is not specified (and `default-src` is also not specified) then no restrictions are applied.

That means that no CSP is equivalent to an empty CSP where everything is allowed (nothing is blocked).